# ImageView not changing in Android

Tags: java, android

i am making a facebook login page , importing image too, my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    info = findViewById(R.id.info);
    profile = findViewById(R.id.profile);
    login = findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            String usrid=loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
            info.setText("user ID: "+usrid);


            profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.abs);//doesn't work
            profile.getLayoutParams().height=20;//it's work


            String imgURL ="https://graph.facebook.com/"+usrid+"/picture?type=large";
            Picasso.get().load(imgURL).fit().into(profile);//does not work

        }
```

and the xml of the image:

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/info"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
```

i tried to change the photo using `Picasso` but doesn't work
i tried using a photo i have used before `R.drawable.abs`, doesn't work also
changing the hieght of the imageview works

so what is wrong?

Comment: Add a static image as a src in the xml for the imageview and share the screenshot of it pls.

Comment: Your foreground may block the image. So Image is loaded but foreground covers it. Can you try after removing your foreground?

Comment: @UzaySan yes i think that's what happen,but how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the forground in your xml is needed but you should be able to replace it with this in your java code:

```java
Picasso.get()
.load(imgURL)
.placeholder(R.drawable. ic_launcher_background)
.fit()
.into(profile);
```

This will replace the placeholder once the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

changing `android:foreground` to `app:srcCompat` solve it